# Firebase: child of child extract value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: mydb]

how can I extract all the "name" values contained in DATA?

I tried this to extract a single name but it doesn't work:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ALL");
Query query = myRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("pluto");
```

Comment: Hey Toppy. You've probably noticed that your question got some downvotes. I upvoted to get rid of some of that, but in general you can prevent a lot of downvoting by: 1) using the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make sure your code shows up correctly formatted and highlighted, 2) posting textual content as text, instead of an image. For example, the screenshot could/should've been actual JSON. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. The code you shared only declares a query. It doesn't read anything from Firebase yet.
2. You're trying to order/filter in a child property, but are not specifying the full path to that property.

The second one is easiest to fix:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ALL");
Query query = myRef.orderByChild("DATA/name").equalTo("pluto");
```

And then you can read the results with:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("Firebase", snapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("Firebase", snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I edited it so the log is working
Log.i("Firebase", snapshot.child("**DATA/name**").getValue(String.class));

If I want to print all the names, how should I do it?